# Html.ListBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am trying to re-select items in a listbox with asp.net mvc

```
Html.ListBox("SupplierId",
             new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Id", "Name", Model.SelectedSuppliers))
```

Here is the viewdata

```
var viewData = new ViewData.SubstrateEditViewData(
               new DataAccess.SubstrateRepository().GetItemById(id),
               new DataAccess.SupplierRepository().GetItems(),
               new DataAccess.SupplierSubstrateRepository().GetItems().Where(s =>  s.SubstrateId ==id).Select(s => s.Supplier));
```

for some reason its not selected the items even tho I can see the Model.SelectedSupplier containing two Supplier objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Note what only ids of items should be passed to *selectedValues* parameter of *MultiSelectList()* method so you should use

```
Html.ListBox("SupplierId", new MultiSelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Id", "Name",
    Model.SelectedSuppliers.Select(s => s.Id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) for the SelectList constructor refers to a single value.  It does't look like passing in a List or IEnumerable of values will result in a listbox with multiple values selected.

Comment: I have changed to MultiSelectList

Comment: Still no luck will try some more variants

Comment: Html.ListBox("SupplierId", new MultiSelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Id", "Name", Model.Suppliers)) should in theory select all the items. But it does not

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem a few weeks ago. The default extension methods for MultiSelect lists do not behave as expected. I ended up just looping through the items myself and setting their `selected` property manually.